# In C, what happens to the stack when we have a return statement which returns a function call?

Tags: c, function, stack, stack-frame

im uderstanding the stack in C lenguage, but I have a question; please look at this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int x){
    if(x==0){
        return;
    }
    else{
        printf("x is equal to 1");
    }
    return function(x-1);
}

void main(){
    function(1);
    return;
}
```

So, first the stack frame (or activation record) of `main` function its stored on the stack, when we call `function(1)` the stack frame of `function(1)` gets stored on the stack too; in the `function(1)` we enter the else statement and we encounter `return function(0);`, so my question is, what happens here?, the stack frame of `function(1)` gets popped from the stack because of the return statement and the stack frame of `function(0)` gets stored in the stack? or the stack still has the stack frames of `main` and `function(1)` and the stack frame of `function(0)` gets stored as well (having now 3 stack frames in the stack)?

If the second possibility is the right one, so in `function(0)` we enter the if statement and because of return, `function(0)` stack frame gets popped from the stack, and then `function(1)` gets popped and finally `main` gets popped from the stack?

Comment: The code shown does not compile (should not compile).  You should not attempt to return the value from a function that does not return a value.

Comment: Other issues aside, the stack is [LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)).

Comment: The C standard doesn't describe such things. The C standard doesn't even require (nor mention) things like call stacks.

Comment: But it compiles perfectly, no warnings or errors, at least in GBD online

Comment: `void` means that the function does NOT return a value, which means that anything other than `return;` should be a compiler error. You need to understand what a function return value is (and is not) before you go any further. Enable all compiler hints/warnings/errors while you're learning. If the compiler you're using does not give you any of those things on the code you've posted, find a better compiler.

Comment: Thabks ken!, and thanks to all of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your compiler and the settings you compile with support it, tail call optimization<sup>1</sup> *may* occur, and in your case the stack space for `function(0)` reuses the stack space for `function(1)`.

However, this is not guaranteed in C and should not be counted on.

Without this optimization, all of your stack frames will accrue, and given a sufficiently large initial value passed into `function` you will get a stack overflow error.

As noted by Jonathan Leffler in comments, you should not return the result of the recursive call, as `function` is a void function. Further, the `else` is extraneous given the way control flow is handled.

```
void function(int x) {
    if (x == 0) {
        return;
    }
    
    printf("x is equal to 1");   
    function(x-1);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> recommended further reading: [What is tail call optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization)

Comment: Thanks Chris!, but let me see if i really understand, so, if my compiler has this optimizacion then function(0) stack frame will replace function(1) stack frame right? this according to my exact code right?

And if my compiler doesnt not have this optimizacion then the second case i wrote will present right?

But now

Comment: So i should not return anything in a void type function right? but i s it ok to write "return;" just for legibility reasons in void functions? is this correct?

And well, doing the changes to the function definition you wrote, all you have said applies again for this new code (the two cases depending on the optimization)?

Comment: Yes, a bare `return` for control flow purposes is fine.